# Animating Between backBarButtonItem and UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to get a smooth animation between the backBarButtonItem and a cancel button when a tableView switches between edit mode.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = editing ? [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:nil] : self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButton animated:YES];
}
```

This correctly changes the leftBarButtonItem, but the change is instant rather than an animated transition as expected. I've also tried various things with `[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];`, but all the resulting animations are slightly wonky.

Anyone have any ideas with this, the above code works with two UIBarButtonItems, but breaks with the backBarButtonItem.

I'd appreciate any help, Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is my current best solution, the animation still seems slightly off to me though.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:nil] animated:YES];
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the change in a UIView animation block:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
    }];
```

You can then tinker with the speed of animation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this provides a suitable fade animation from the barButton to the backButton, but a strange scale animation in the other direction.